# Disable profile controller in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring boot with external oauth2 server.
I configure it using standard spring boot oauth2 resourceserver and spring data rest.
Application expose profile controller, but this function is usless in this situation.

I try to switch off this, but I can't find info about it.
Who knows the way to disable it?

Comment: Does this help you ? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1480